# Fix the color order in a plotly gantt chart

Tags: pandas, plotly-python, gantt-chart

Trying to plot a gantt chart using plotly and a pandas dataframe. The plot comes fine, except the colors are in a different order.

Here is the dataframe

```
                  Goss     got
timestamp                     
16-01-21 10:00:09    M   Item1
04-02-21 20:28:30    T   Item2
06-02-21 00:45:57    V   Item3
24-07-21 11:07:39    M   Item4
26-08-21 16:15:01    T   Item5
28-08-21 14:05:13    I   Item6
02-09-21 16:57:26    D   Item7
15-09-21 15:35:07    M   Item8
13-10-21 18:19:42    D   Item9
18-10-21 02:39:40    G  Item10
31-10-21 22:07:27    D  Item11
01-11-21 09:58:21    I  Item12
01-11-21 11:37:44    V  Item13
28-11-21 10:44:39    K  Item14
28-11-21 14:52:39    M  Item15
29-11-21 18:40:32    G  Item16
01-12-21 23:34:00    G  Item17
03-12-21 00:11:11    T  Item18
05-12-21 15:55:50    G  Item19
```

We process the above data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
from plotly import figure_factory as FF

gdf=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+') #with this the df data above can be copied and read to a df
gdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
gdf.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(gdf.timestamp,format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
gdf=pd.concat([gdf.timestamp.shift(),gdf], axis=1)
gdf.columns=['Start', 'Finish', 'Goss', 'Task']
gdf.at[0,'Start'] = pd.Timestamp("2021-01-01-00-00-00")
gfig = FF.create_gantt(gdf, colors=['#FFFF00',
                                    '#A0522D',
                                    '#808000',
                                    '#008000',
                                    '#FF0000',
                                    '#00CED1',
                                    '#00FFFF'], 
                       index_col='Goss', show_colorbar=True, 
                       bar_width=0.2, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
plotly.offline.plot(gfig, filename='gorge.html')
```

Read the data from clipboard using
`gdf=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')`

My data gets improperly colored. I tried few reorder of the colors, didn't come out correctly. The correct order should be as given in the `dict` below, item followed by the color it should have.

```
{'T':'#FFFF00','G':'#A0522D','M':'#808000','D':'#008000','V':'#FF0000', 'K':'#00CED1',"I':'#00FFFF'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the colors after the figure is created.

```
cmap = {'T':'#FFFF00','G':'#A0522D','M':'#808000','D':'#008000','V':'#FF0000', 'K':'#00CED1',"I":'#00FFFF'}
gfig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(fillcolor=cmap[t.name]) if t.name in cmap.keys() else t)
```

Comment: This works!    Will accept in a bit